# Failure to update Laravel 5.1 to 5.2 (these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability)

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

Couple weeks ago I asked this question about trying to upgrade from Laravel 5.1 to 5.2 - [Updating Larael from 5.1.35 to 5.2.* - fails to upgrade symfony/css-selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38980253/updating-larael-from-5-1-35-to-5-2-fails-to-upgrade-symfony-css-selector)

Although I was given very nice and clear answer, that did not help. As instructed, I have updated `"lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel"` to `"~5.1"`, but I still have the same error.

My `composer.json`

```
  {
  "name": "laravel/laravel",
  "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
  "keywords": [
    "framework",
    "laravel"
  ],
  "license": "MIT",
  "type": "project",
  "require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "laravel/framework": "5.2.*",
    "aws/aws-sdk-php-laravel": "~3.0",
    "vinkla/hashids": "^1.1",
    "cartalyst/sentinel": "~2.0.1",
    "baum/baum": "~1.1",
    "robclancy/presenter": "1.3.*",
    "barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper": "^2.0",
    "league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3": "~1.0",
    "intervention/image": "^2.2",
    "rap2hpoutre/laravel-log-viewer": "^0.2.8",
    "league/fractal": "^0.12.0",
    "ramsey/uuid": "~2.8",
    "lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel": "~5.1",
    "torann/geoip": "0.2.*@dev",
    "mailchimp/mailchimp": "^2.0",
    "iron-io/iron_mq": "~2.0",
    "aws/aws-sdk-php": "~3.0",
    "justinrainbow/json-schema": "~1.3",
    "sybio/gif-frame-extractor": "^1.0",
    "coldume/imagecraft": "dev-gif-optimization",
    "pragmarx/firewall": "^0.5.2",
    "get-stream/stream-laravel": "dev-master",
    "roumen/sitemap": "2.5.*",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~6.0",
    "bugsnag/bugsnag-laravel": "1.*",
    "cviebrock/image-validator": "^2.0",
    "toin0u/geocoder-laravel": "@stable",
    "badawy/embedly": "^1.0",
    "facebook/webdriver": "^1.0",
    "scotteh/php-dom-wrapper": "dev-composer-symfony-fix",
    "scotteh/php-goose": "dev-composer-guzzle-fix",
    "doctrine/dbal": "^2.5",
    "mandrill/mandrill": "1.0.*"
  },
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "vcs",
      "url": "https://github.com/zmike808GS/imagecraft"
    },
    {
      "type": "vcs",
      "url": "https://github.com/zmike808GS/php-goose"
    },
    {
      "type": "vcs",
      "url": "https://github.com/zmike808GS/php-dom-wrapper"
    }
  ],
  "require-dev": {
    "symfony/dom-crawler": "~3.0",
    "symfony/css-selector": "~3.0",
    "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
    "phpspec/phpspec": "~2.1",
    "laracasts/testdummy": "~2.0"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "classmap": [
      "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
      "*********************": "****"
    }
  },
  "autoload-dev": {
    "classmap": [
      "tests"
    ]
  },
  "scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
      "php artisan clear-compiled",
      "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "pre-update-cmd": [
      "php artisan clear-compiled"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
      "php artisan clear-compiled",
      "php artisan ide-helper:generate",
      "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-root-package-install": [
      "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
      "php artisan key:generate"
    ]
  },
  "config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "github-oauth": {
      "github.com": "**************************************"
    }
  }
}
```

The full text of error:

```
>> composer update
php artisan clear-compiled
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - laravel/framework v5.1.43 requires symfony/css-selector 2.7.* -> satisfiable by symfony/css-selector[2.7.x-dev, v2.7.0, v2.7.0-BETA1, v2.7.0-BETA2, v2.7.1, v2.7.10, v2.7.11, v2.7.12, v2.7.13, v2.7.14, v2.7.15, v2.7.16, v2.7.2, v2.7.3, v2.7.4, v2.7.5, v2.7.6, v2.7.7, v2.7.8, v2.7.9] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.45
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.44
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.43
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.42
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework 5.2.41
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.40
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.39
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.38
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.37
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.36
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.35
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.34
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.33
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.32
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.31
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.30
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.29
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.28
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.27
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.26
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.25
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.24
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.23
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.22
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.21
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.20
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.19
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.18
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.17
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.16
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.15
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.14
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.13
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.12
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.11
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.10
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.9
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.8
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.7
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.6
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.5
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.4
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.3
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.2
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.1
    - vinkla/hashids 1.1.0 requires illuminate/support 5.0.*|5.1.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.1.43], illuminate/support[v5.0.0, v5.0.22, v5.0.25, v5.0.26, v5.0.28, v5.0.33, v5.0.4, v5.1.1, v5.1.13, v5.1.16, v5.1.2, v5.1.20, v5.1.22, v5.1.25, v5.1.28, v5.1.30, v5.1.31, v5.1.41, v5.1.6, v5.1.8].
    - vinkla/hashids 1.1.0 requires illuminate/support 5.0.*|5.1.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.1.43], illuminate/support[v5.0.0, v5.0.22, v5.0.25, v5.0.26, v5.0.28, v5.0.33, v5.0.4, v5.1.1, v5.1.13, v5.1.16, v5.1.2, v5.1.20, v5.1.22, v5.1.25, v5.1.28, v5.1.30, v5.1.31, v5.1.41, v5.1.6, v5.1.8].
    - don't install laravel/framework v5.2.0|don't install illuminate/support v5.1.1
    - don't install laravel/framework v5.2.0|don't install illuminate/support v5.1.13
    - don't install laravel/framework v5.2.0|don't install illuminate/support v5.1.16
    - don't install laravel/framework v5.2.0|don't install illuminate/support v5.1.2
    - don't install laravel/framework v5.2.0|don't install illuminate/support v5.1.20
    - don't install laravel/framework v5.2.0|don't install illuminate/support v5.1.22
    - don't install laravel/framework v5.2.0|don't install illuminate/support v5.1.25
    - don't install laravel/framework v5.2.0|don't install illuminate/support v5.1.28
    - don't install laravel/framework v5.2.0|don't install illuminate/support v5.1.30
    - don't install laravel/framework v5.2.0|don't install illuminate/support v5.1.31
    - don't install laravel/framework v5.2.0|don't install illuminate/support v5.1.41
    - don't install laravel/framework v5.2.0|don't install illuminate/support v5.1.6
    - don't install laravel/framework v5.2.0|don't install illuminate/support v5.1.8
    - don't install laravel/framework v5.2.0|don't install illuminate/support v5.0.22
    - don't install laravel/framework v5.2.0|don't install illuminate/support v5.0.25
    - don't install laravel/framework v5.2.0|don't install illuminate/support v5.0.26
    - don't install laravel/framework v5.2.0|don't install illuminate/support v5.0.28
    - don't install laravel/framework v5.2.0|don't install illuminate/support v5.0.33
    - don't install laravel/framework v5.2.0|don't install illuminate/support v5.0.0
    - don't install laravel/framework v5.2.0|don't install illuminate/support v5.0.4
    - Installation request for laravel/framework 5.2.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[5.2.41, v5.2.0, v5.2.1, v5.2.10, v5.2.11, v5.2.12, v5.2.13, v5.2.14, v5.2.15, v5.2.16, v5.2.17, v5.2.18, v5.2.19, v5.2.2, v5.2.20, v5.2.21, v5.2.22, v5.2.23, v5.2.24, v5.2.25, v5.2.26, v5.2.27, v5.2.28, v5.2.29, v5.2.3, v5.2.30, v5.2.31, v5.2.32, v5.2.33, v5.2.34, v5.2.35, v5.2.36, v5.2.37, v5.2.38, v5.2.39, v5.2.4, v5.2.40, v5.2.42, v5.2.43, v5.2.44, v5.2.45, v5.2.5, v5.2.6, v5.2.7, v5.2.8, v5.2.9].
    - Installation request for vinkla/hashids ^1.1 -> satisfiable by vinkla/hashids[1.1.0].
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These errors are always best to read from bottom-up, in my opinion.

Your `composer.json` requires `vinkla/hashids ^1.1`. That means it'll go up to, but not beyond, version 1.99999... The highest version satisfying that, [1.1](https://packagist.org/packages/vinkla/hashids#1.1.0), requires Laravel contracts up through 5.1. Thus, vinkla/hashids is pinning you to a Laravel 5.1 install. This pinning is then requiring you use `symfony/css-selector ^2.7`, which conflicts with your explicit request for `^3.0`.

To solve this problem, you need to either allow [`vinkla/hashids ^2.2`](https://packagist.org/packages/vinkla/hashids#2.2.0), or remove the need for the package altogether. So, try:

`php composer.phar require vinkla/hashids:^2.2`

Then run your tests and confirm that your code works with the new version of `vinkla/hashids`.